# Play 2 GET method maximum length

Tags: java, playframework

I am using `Play framework (Java)` to create `REST` apis for my application.
I am facing problem with length of `REST API` with `GET`.

I need below web method to be used:

```
public static Result getregistereduser(String userlist)
{

    //userlist is string of user numbers seperated by "$" , 

    .....

    ....

}
```

in routes I have :

```
GET    /getregistereduser                   controllers.Application.getregistereduser(userlist)
```

Problem I am facing is when userlist is large it only takes partial string.

Comment: If you are calling the API from browser then I think its the browser that is imposing the limit. IE has limit of 2000 characters.

Comment: Hi Subir, I am trying to use this from mobile app not from browser.

Comment: The framework used by the app probably has a limit as well. What mobile device do you use (what type? what OS?)? Do you a custom created app or something existing?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what version of Play you're using, but Play shouldn't truncate long GET requests. You should get an error response if the GET request is too large for it to handle.

Up until recently that error would be a `500 Internal Server Error` caused by an `org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.TooLongFrameException`. [With Play 2.3.0](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/2512) (not yet released) you'll get a `414 Request URI too long` response instead.

Play inherits its HTTP header parsing from Netty. The first line of the header (`GET /path HTTP/1.1`) can be up to 4096 bytes by default. This can be configured by with the `http.netty.maxInitialLineLength` system property (see this [mailing list thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/LLk8Fkmlj48/2BjPmMNtE_cJ)).

I agree that you're most likely seeing problem with your HTTP client. I'd recommend using a debugging proxy like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) (or a free alternative) to look at exactly what HTTP requests your client is sending.

Comment: The correct should be `play.server.netty.maxInitialLineLength` according to `NettyServer.scala`